# CMake: add a directory prefix to `target_include_directories(...)` file #includes

Tags: c++, cmake, include, prefix

I am using the [Crypto++](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp) library in my C++ project, and have installed it with the following (minimised) CMake code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(CMakeAddLibraryPrefixIncludes)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(CryptoPP
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git
        GIT_TAG master)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(CryptoPP)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

add_library(CryptoPP INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(CryptoPP INTERFACE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/cryptopp-src)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} CryptoPP)
```

Because the library has every header file in the top-level directory, all these files are accessible as `#include <aes.h>` for example. Is there a way that I can make it so that every file from `CryptoPP` is only accessible through a directory prefix like `#include <cryptopp/aes.h>`?

Comment: The headers of cryptopp itself include each other without a prefix (e.g. `aes.h` does `#include "rijndael.h"`). Unless you modify them to add a prefix, you have to make them available without a prefix.

Comment: @spectras I was thinking that the headers themselves would still be able to do this and work correctly because they are in the same directory, where-as when `#include`-ing them I could link them with a prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the folder for downloading sources by providing `SOURCE_DIR` to `FetchContent_Declare`. You can then use the parent folder of `cryptopp_SOURCE_DIR` as your include path.

```
FetchContent_Declare(CryptoPP
        SOURCE_DIR ${FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR}/cryptopp-src/cryptopp
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git
        GIT_TAG master)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(CryptoPP)

# ...

target_include_directories(CryptoPP INTERFACE "${cryptopp_SOURCE_DIR}/..")
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, I just had to add the line `set(FETCH_CONTENT_BASE_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_deps)`